# Ignoring all files in a directory except one in GIT using negate prefix

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I want to ignore all the files in a directory except one file.

I do the following in my git bash.

```sh
$ mkdir dir_to_ignore
$ cd dir_to_ignore
$ vi file_to_ignore.txt 
# (I put some content and save the file)
$ vi second_file.txt
# (Some text and then save the file. I dont wish this file to be ignored)
$ cd ..
$ vi .gitignore
```

I put the following content into `.gitignore` file:

```
dir_to_ignore/
!dir_to_ignore/second_file.txt
```

But now when I do `git status`, I don't see `second_file.txt` as an untracked file.
Why is this happening?

Comment: according to this article atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore "Nope! Due to a performance-related quirk in Git, you can not negate a file that is ignored due to a pattern matching a directory" – camino just now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems kind of odd to ignore a directory, yet try to track a file within the ignored directory, because to track the file, you would probably need to know the **full path** to the file, including the directory that it's in.

If you change your `.gitignore` file to this instead:

```
dir_to_ignore/*
!second_file.txt
```

that will ignore all files under `dir_to_ignore` except for `second_file.txt`.  You'll still need to track the directory though in order to also track `second_file.txt`.

Comment: Antoher way to achieve this is to ignore the whole dir as usual, and `git add file/to/keep -f`, which will force the file in

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive what you want by creating a `.gitignore` file in the `dir_to_ignore` directory and put this in it

```
*
!second_file.txt
!.gitignore
```

(Assuming that you probably want to version control the new `.gitignore` file too)

Comment: This works, I tested it on my machine.  Still seems odd to ignore the containing directory though.

Answer (score 0):

With a rule like `dir_to_ignore/` git will ignore that directory completely. It will never look inside and therefore a second rule like `!dir_to_ignore/second_file.txt` will never be matched.

To get the desired effect, instead of ignoring the directory itself you need to ignore all files in the directory, like `dir_to_ignore/*`. Together with the second rule git will now ignore all files except the second_file.

This kind of situation gets even more tricky when you decide to ignore `dir_to_ignore` except of `dir_to_ignore/some/long/path`. - Most of the time it is better not to use exceptions and just state what you want to ignore. If you need exceptions you should think again about you project structure.

BTW: Be aware that a line like `dir_to_ignore/` will ignore *all* directories with that name through the whole project, whereas `/dir_to_ignore/` will ignore only the one in the current directory.